# 'target' _blank not opening in new window

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

I have links on a page that gets populated from another cms view. i am trying to open it onto a different page by adding in the following using jquery

```
function OpenMenuTabsInDifferentWindow() {
          $('#menu ul li a[title ="test"]').attr('target', '_blank');

      }
      OpenMenuTabsInDifferentWindow();
```

however the attr gets added to the link but it doesnt open it up onto a new window tab, what am i doing wrong?

this is my html

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
<li class=""><a dataid="49689" onclick="AuroraJS.Modules.GetContentForModule(&quot;Page&quot;,49689,&quot;test&quot;); return false;" title="test" href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stackoverflow</a></li></ul> //if you notice the target gets added
    </div>
```

Comment: `target="_blank"` is only for  href link, not  for JS code of anything. JS  can open a new window on his side of code

Comment: The `onclick=` will fire before the `a` default.  So depends on what GetContentForModule does; likely it includes `e.preventDefault()` or equivalent so your link won't attempt to navigate to a new window.

Comment: So what can I do to achieve this?